# System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) вернул null

Tags: c#, xml

Есть метод postXmlData для отправки и получение Xml запросов/ответов. После получение ответа показываю на консоль атрибуты который начинаются с буква f, но получаю ошибку System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element(...) вернул null. Что я делаю не так?

postXmlData:

```
public static XmlDocument postXMLData(string xml)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Requests.url);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    var result = new XmlDocument();
                    result.LoadXml(responseText);
                    return result;
                }
            }

            throw new Exception();
        }
```

Ответ от запроса:

```
<response result="0">
    <prov>
        <getStatus result="0">
            <pay date="2023-02-08T19:44:33+03:00" fatal="false" id="8022140013003" result="0" status="2" uid="26775263057008" value-date="2023-02-08T19:44:40+03:00">
            </pay>
        </getStatus>
    </prov>
</response>
```

Вывод атрибуты с использованием XElement:

```
XmlDocument doc = postXMLData(Requests.getStatus("08022140013003"));
            XElement e = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));
            Console.WriteLine(e); //here ok
           
            IEnumerable<XAttribute> attrs1 = e.Element("response").Element("prov").Element("getStatus").Element("pay")?.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("f"));
            Console.WriteLine(attrs1);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Всё не так! Используется жутко устаревший `WebRequest`, спутаны кодировки ASCII и UTF-8, не используется выражение `using`, используется устаревший `XmlDocument`, который тут же преобразуется в `XElement`, выбрасывается пустой `new Exception()`, не несущий никакой информации об ошибке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глупая ошибка, вы пытаетесь взять `.Element("response")` у какого элемента? Подумайте, посмотрите внимательно.

Вот решение:

```cs
IEnumerable<XAttribute> attrs1 = e.Element("prov").Element("getStatus").Element("pay")?.Attributes().Where(a => a.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("f"));
```

---

`HttpWebRequest` устарел лет 10 назад. Вот захотите потом перейти на новый .NET 8, который выйдет осенью 2023 года, а там `HttpWebRequest` вообще будет отсутствовать.

Метод `postXMLData` написан нелогично, на входе строка, на выходе `XmlDocument`. Ну ок, не меняя логики перепишу на `HttpClient`:

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<XmlDocument> PostXMLDataAsync(string url, string xml)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = new XmlDocument();
            result.LoadXml(responseText);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Пользоваться так

```cs
XmlDocument doc = await PostXMLDataAsync(Requests.url, Requests.getStatus("08022140013003"));
```

---

Даже если категорически не хотите использовать `HttpClient`, поправьте хотя-бы кодировку отправляемых данных:

```cs
bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
```

Comment: получаю ошибку: `Ошибка CS4033 Оператор await можно использовать только в методах с модификатором async. Попробуйте пометить этот метод модификатором async и изменить тип его возвращаемого значения на Task.` Когда вызываю: `XmlDocument doc = await PostXMLDataAsync(Requests.url, Requests.getStatus("08022140013003"));`

Comment: @JohnPaulJohns что мешает модификатор `async` добавить? Ну или хотя-бы бегло прогуглиться на тему async/await? :) Я ж не телепат, не вижу, что там у вас находится за пределами показанного кода, верно?

Comment: @JohnPaulJohns если это консольный мейн, то замените `void Main` на `async Task Main`. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/13.3.php

Comment: вы чудо, поменял postXmlData на PostXMLDataAsync все отлично, но после того хотел вывести атрибуты как первый на консоле показывает `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]`. Не знаю может код у вас работает отлично но уже второй день мучаюсь с этим вопросом

Comment: @JohnPaulJohns `.First()` или `foreach`. Вы коллекцию вывести пытаетесь. Это кстати тоже глупая ошибка :) будьте внимательней.