# Преобразование IEnumerable<XAttribute> в string

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Я хочу преобразовать IEnumerable в string. Как это можно сделать:

```
 IEnumerable<XAttribute> attrs1 = e.Elements("providers")
                .Elements("getPaymentStatus")
                .Elements("payment")
                .Elements("extras")
                .Attributes()
                .Where(a => a.Name.LocalName.StartsWith("P"));

            foreach (var a in attrs1)
                Console.WriteLine(a);
```

Пробовал IEnumerable ошибку выдает.
И еще как можно вывести только значение атрибутов, у меня показывает атрибут со значением.

Comment: После `a` поставить точку `.` - IDE вывалит список членов типа. Выбрать нужный.

Comment: А что вы хотите получить на вывод в консоли - надо догадаться?

Comment: Сейчас в `a` хранится список атрибутов. Ты хочешь вывести какой-то конкретный? Или все?

Comment: @Grundy конкретный

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{a.Name} = {a.Value}")`

Comment: @JohnPaulJohns, какой из? У тебя есть коллекция, по какому признаку ты хочешь выбрать из нее элемент?

Comment: @aepot это не сработает, `a` - это `IEnumerable` а не `XAttribute`

Comment: @Grundy `a` это `XAttribute`. В цикле же

Comment: @aepot, Хотя возможно и нет . Либо ошибка из другого кода, либо одно из двух

Comment: @Grundy это продолжение прошлого вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1497782/373567, я этот код писал и видел как он работает. Простое форматирование вывода и обращение к Name и Value артибута решает проблему.

Comment: @aepot, забавно _Преобразование IEnumerable<XAttribute> в string_ - с кодом, который уже это делает . хмммм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно значение - обращайтесь к значению

[XAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute).[Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.value)

```cs
foreach (var a in attrs1)
    Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
```

Или так, если нужен только первый попавшийся

```cs
Console.WriteLine(attrs1.First().Value);
```